# LOAD INFILE REPLACE Not working as expected

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import a txt file using LOAD INFILE like below.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/xxxx/cloud_20181003.txt' INTO TABLE cloud_log_test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (CACHECACHESTATUS,CACHERESPONSEBYTES);
```

It is importing properly. The problem is My data is in Key value format. So While inserting in to cell it is inserting like `"CacheCacheStatus":"unknown"` for the column CacheCacheStatus. It needs to store the values alone like `unknown`. I have tried to add Replace like below but it is inserting complete cell as null.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/xxxx/cloud_20181003.txt' INTO TABLE cloud_log_test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (CACHECACHESTATUS,CACHERESPONSEBYTES) SET CacheCacheStatus = REPLACE(@CacheCacheStatus,'"CacheCacheStatus":"','');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have missed '@' in my query. :-) Working now.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/xxxx/cloud_20181003.txt' INTO TABLE cloud_log_test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (@CACHECACHESTATUS,CACHERESPONSEBYTES) SET CacheCacheStatus = REPLACE(@CacheCacheStatus,'"CacheCacheStatus":"','');
```